# RabbitMQ cant start due to an error on log fomatter config

Tags: docker, logging, rabbitmq

I'm using RabbitMQ 3.8.5-management with the following config:

```
log.file = rabbit.log 
log.dir = /var/log/rabbitmq 
log.file.level = info 
log.file.formatter = json 
log.file.rotation.date = $D0
```

I get the following error:

```
12:45:12.131 [error] You've tried to set log.file.formatter, but there is no setting with that name.
12:45:12.134 [error]   Did you mean one of these?
12:45:12.182 [error]     log.file.level
12:45:12.182 [error]     log.file
12:45:12.182 [error]     log.file.rotation.date
12:45:12.182 [error] Error preparing configuration in phase transform_datatypes:
12:45:12.183 [error]   - Conf file attempted to set unknown variable: log.file.formatter
```

According to the documentation log.file.formatter should work - what is wrong?

- checked documentation on RabbitMQ.
- checked other SO posts.
- entered the container and remove the config - it works without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like JSON logging and the `log.file.formatter` setting was added with [RabbitMQ 3.9.0 release](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/releases/tag/v3.9.0).

Try upgrading if possible.